# how to reduce ffmpeg compression time

Tags: android, performance, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Hi I am new with FFmpeg and I am trying to compress the video file by using this command

```
"-y", "-i", source_file_path, "-s", "480x640", "-r", "24", "-c:v", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-b:v", "512k", "-bufsize",
      "3968k", "-crf", "26", "-c:a", "copy", destination_file_path
```

currently, it's taking 3 minutes to compress a 1-minute long file how I can reduce the compressing process time. I am using FFmpeg 4.0. thanks

**EDITED**

I am using an android phone to compress the video and I am using this [FFmpeg git library](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android)

Comment: Using the `-preset ultrafast` option should be fast enough. And don't forget, compression time is related to the video complexity (temporal and spatial).

Comment: Does your Android device support NEON?

Comment: Hi @llogan, I am developing this app to put it on the play store and in this situation the device is not fixed.

Comment: I also have a doubt @llogan, what kind of compression used by WhatsApp how did they are very sure about the result size of an uncompressed file, thanks.

Comment: ok this is uncompressed file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m7hlHM8RelJ5iEhXeWUHL3HjRbKC2Y4K
here is the compressed file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HEk7x8lkmDPN_nUpk1mkS-uKxD853We1